# Ruby Regex match method

Tags: ruby, regex

I was giving this regex `/\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]{2,}\z/` and I'm to use it in order to verify the validity of an email address.

This is my first Ruby code and I'm not sure how to do it. I was told to use the `.match` method, which returns `MatchData` object. But how do I go on verifying that the `MatchData` object confirms the validity?

I attempted using the following, but it seems that it's accepting any string, even not an email address.

```
#Register new handler
def register_handler

    email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]{2,}\z/
    email = "invalid"
    unless email =~ email_regex then
        puts("Insert your e-mail address:")
        email = gets
    end

    puts("email received")


end
```

What is the correct way to do this? Either using `.match` or the method I attempted above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex matches email addresses:

```
'invalid' =~ email_regex
=> nil # which boolean value is false

'email@example.com' =~ email_regex
=> 0 # which boolean value is true
```

however:

```
"email@example.com\n" =~ email_regex
=> nil
```

The newline character `\n` is appended by `gets` to every input.

That is why, the `until` loop will run forever regardless of what you will type in the terminal. The matching result will always be `nil` because of the newline character.

Try using `gets.chomp`, which will trim the newline character and your code should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Edited the regex and put () to capture group and the beginning and the end

```
re = /^([\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]{2,})$/m
str = 'a@b.com
p@qasdf.com
adbadf@bwdsfqaf.com
....
a@bdotcom


aasdf.com

www.yahoo.com'

# Print the match result
str.scan(re) do |match|
    puts match.to_s
end
```

[Running sample code](http://ideone.com/8xkQ5M)